# aspnet 5 mvc 6 - how to edit multiple records?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to extend the Steve Woods **'To Do List'** ASP.Net 5 MVC 6  project by adding a Percent Complete field, and allowing edit of the Percent Complete for each ToDoListItem.

[Let's Build - Steve Woods ToDoList](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp5K8t71jE8&feature=iv&src_vid=_7u9dOyK92o&annotation_id=annotation_578736801)

My view displays data and I can enter new Percent Complete values; however when I click on Save, a new empty record is written to my ToDoListItems table.  The new record does not contain the Percent Complete number I entered, either.

My **View** contains @model

```
@model IEnumerable<todoy6.Models.ToDoListItems>
```

I am using an asp-action to return (post) to the Controller

```
<form asp-action="Index">
```

The View then contains a table laid out like this

```
        @foreach (ToDoListItems item in (IEnumerable<ToDoListItems>)ViewData["ToDoListItems"])
    {  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@item.ID].ID" value="@item.ID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@item.ID].ApplicationUserID" value="@item.ApplicationUserID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @*<label asp-for=@item.Price class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>*@
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for=@item.Pct class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for=@item.Pct class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }   @*for each *@
```

I think my problem is in the way I am iterating through the ToDoListItems with the @Item.ID values.

My **Controller** is running this code:

```
       [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(ToDoListItems todoitems)  //declare and name the todolistitems object returned on POST
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Update(todoitems);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(todoitems);
    }
```

My model is valid, but the modified records seem to be coming in unidentified (no ID?) and being entered into the table as new records.

Answer (score 4):

I am the tutorial author .. I was going to cover this in Part 3 but due to illness and time constraints I've been unable to produce the video (and the two after that!).

Basically the code you're using is adding more and more and more todo list items because you're calling the "Post" method which was (at the current stage of the tutorial) simply designed to keep adding more and more and more (for illustration purposes).

You'll need to alter it to present the items as text on the page (not form elements!), and any new todo list items will need to be rendered as form controls.

I'll publish Part 3 shortly, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: thank you for the original tutorial.  it got me a very long way and is much appreciated!     Is it possible to allow the Percent Complete to be a form control?   I want the user to be able to go down their list and revise the Percent Complete without leaving the page.  I am Post-ing from Index.cshtml back to Index in the ToDoListsController, without using an Edit view.